# Typescript typing for the array of components in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to define an array of components, which are basically steps. I tried giving the type to steps:

```
const steps = ref<Component[]>([
  Component1,
  Component2, 
  Component3,
]);
```

But this doesn't works, what will be the correct type for steps

Answer (score 0):

why not just use inferred type?

```js
const steps = ref([
  Component1,
  Component2, 
  Component3,
]);
```

when you mouse hover on `steps`, most IDE should show the inferred type.